# How to show multiple columns values from db in a single row android

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, listview

This is my code :

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   //populateListView();
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

    ListView obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayContact.class);

            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayContact.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

This is my getallcontact code.....

```
          public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts()
{
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(!res.isAfterLast()){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL)));
        res.moveToNext();
    } 
    return array_list;
}
```

And the output is..
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjbjs.jpg)

How can i show both **name** and **email** in a single row?

Comment: You can create custom listview for this otherwise you can concate name and email in single string and add to array_list.

Comment: store everything in a string and add it to array list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding both **`name`** and **`email`** as separate **`listitems`** in your list so **`combine`** them as a single entry.

do this in your while loop

```
 array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)) +"  "+res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL)));
```

instead of this

```
 array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
 array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL)));
```

Plus for little better formatting you can use new line escape sequence "\n"

```
 array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)) +"\n"+res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL)));
```